# UITableView in a Widget

Tags: ios, ios8

I apologize for the vagueness of this question, but has anyone had success with a table view in a widget (iOS 8)? I'm trying to place a table view with dynamic prototypes in a widget, but it only works part of the time. For instance, when I click a cell the whole table will disappear only to instantly reappear. Other times the table will disappear and 'Unable to Load' will take its place.

Any pointers on how to make this work consistently? Is there a limit on the size a widget can be? Am I reloading the table in the wrong spot? I tried to turn off scrolling and bouncing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is posible and it does work. In my experience memory is an issue.  Your widget is probably being killed due to memory constrains. To see what is going on I find most reliable to see the device console (in Xcode Window->Devices->choose your device). You will see a message on why your widget is being killed.

Try reducing the number of rows and removing elements from the cells.

Comment: I concur. I've found that iOS is very tight with memory for widgets and also time taken to initialise.

Comment: Definitely memory usage. Thanks!